# No logs are getting created for JIT handler class for Just In time provision

Tags: saml, jit-handler

I have created JIT handler class and in SSO Setting also have given JIT handler name with Running as My user. I tried putting logs at finest level still didn't getting any logs .  I tried logs for my user still it didn't print any logs, then I tried with Handler class as entity but still no logs even on Developer console.

Thanks
Arun

Comment: It's running under System User, From what I remember it's `Automation Process` user for JIT

Comment: Thanks ytiq for quick reply. Can you please tell me how can i debug logs for same. I have kept my custom handler for JIT and want to see logs.